# CartoDB API to make a table public after an import?

Tags: carto

I am currently using the import API to import my layer data into CartoDB from another application.

My question is whether there is a way to make this table PUBLIC using an API instead of the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Currently CartoDB doesn't support making tables public from the API.